# SQL - JOIN QUERY - SUMMING ISSUE

Tags: sql, join

I am joining 2 tables using the query below.  Its many to many relationship.

The join works fine but creates multiple rows for each item which is expected but the value is also duplicated. How to avoid this? Thanks
As you can see the Current output the value (50000 appears 3 times instead of 1 and 27000 appears 3 times instead of 1)

```
SELECT * FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 ON
T1.Projectex = T2.WBS_Parent
```

**Table 1:**

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+-------+
| Projectex | CAPEX_OPEX | costelmnt | sap_vers | Period | FISCYEAR | VALUE |
+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+-------+
| 0-01081   | CAPEX      |      3416 |       61 |      3 |     2020 | 50000 |
| 0-01081   | OPEX       |      7077 |       30 |      5 |     2020 | 27000 |
+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+--------+----------+-------+
```

**Table2:**

```
+------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| WBS_PARENT | FINANCILAL_YEAR | MEASURE | AMOUNT  |
+------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
| 0-01081    |            2020 | CPX     | 2000000 |
| 0-01081    |            2020 | OPX     |   50000 |
| 0-01081    |            2020 | OPX     | 1000000 |
+------------+-----------------+---------+---------+
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT:**

```
Projectex| CAPEX_OPEX|  costelmnt|  sap_vers|  Period|  FISCYEAR|  VALUE|  
0   0-01081|      CAPEX|       3416|       61|      3|      2020|  50000|   
1   0-01081|      CAPEX|       3416|       61|      3|      2020|  50000|   
2   0-01081|      CAPEX|       3416|       61|      3|      2020|  50000|  
3   0-01081|       OPEX|       7077|       30|      5|      2020|  27000|  
4   0-01081|       OPEX|       7077|       30|      5|      2020|  27000|   
5   0-01081|       OPEX|       7077|       30|      5|      2020|  27000|   

  WBS_PARENT  FINANCILAL_YEAR MEASURE   AMOUNT  
0    0-01081|            2020|     CPX|  2000000  
1    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|    50000  
2    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|  1000000  
3    0-01081|            2020|     CPX|  2000000  
4    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|    50000  
5    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|  1000000
```

**Expected Output:**

Projectex| CAPEX_OPEX|  costelmnt|  sap_vers|  Period|  FISCYEAR|  VALUE|
0   0-01081|      CAPEX|       3416|       61|      3|      2020|  50000|
1   0-01081|      CAPEX|       3416|       61|      3|      2020|
2   0-01081|      CAPEX|       3416|       61|      3|      2020|
3   0-01081|       OPEX|       7077|       30|      5|      2020|  27000|
4   0-01081|       OPEX|       7077|       30|      5|      2020|
5   0-01081|       OPEX|       7077|       30|      5|      2020|

WBS_PARENT  FINANCILAL_YEAR MEASURE   AMOUNT
0    0-01081|            2020|     CPX|  2000000
1    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|    50000
2    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|  1000000
3    0-01081|            2020|     CPX|
4    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|
5    0-01081|            2020|     OPX|

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215292/discussion-on-question-by-user13670066-sql-join-query-summing-issue).

Answer (score 0):

maybe you mean:

```
SELECT 
T1.*
,_T2.TotalAmount
FROM T1
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT WBS_Parent , sum(amount) TotalAmount
FROM T2
GROUP BY WBS_Parent
) _T2 ON _T2.WBS_Parent = T1.Projectex
```

else, it's better to put a sample data output for the result you expect

Comment: Guessing at answers just makes a mess, unclear questions should be downvoted & close voted & commented on for improvement.